# Lotus Notes - concatenation in file line

Tags: concatenation, lotus-notes

I have a fileNum ( =FreeFile() ) in which I want to add the following line

```
del -q name=java prog guide.pdf
```

I tried :

```
Print #fileNum%,{del -q name="}+askme+{"}
```

Where `askme` is the `ws.Prompt(PROMPT_OKCANCELEDITCOMBO,...)` selection result. Prompt gives the possibility to choose some file names, as above there is: `java prog guide.pdf` ( the file names may contain spaces )

But it puts the java prog guide.pdf inside quotes.

I appreciate your time!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It puts the value of the askme variable inside quotes because you have added quotes. In Lotusscript you can use { and } instead of quotes if you need quotes inside your string.

So do this instead:

```
Print #fileNum%,{del -q name=}+askme
```

Comment: Thanks , dear Per Henrik! Also, I should have to deal with the name of files that contains spaces, e.g.: dear man.txt => name=dear man.txt but the script will see it as name=dear .

Comment: Well, the name parameter wasn't a must. I just remove it and it works! : )